# How to minify AngularJS modules

Tags: angularjs

I've broken down our Angularjs application into modules and separated it's components into their respective files.

```
/app
    /components
        calendar.directive.js
        calendar.directive.html
    /people
        people.html
        people-view.html
        people.controller.js
    /event
        event.html
        event-view.html
        event.controller.js
        event.service.js
```

I'm not quite sure about this part.. Do I need to call all these files when I'm building my application?

```
<script src="calendar.js"></script>
<script src="people.controller.js"></script>
<script src="event.controller.js"></script>
```

Or is there a way to combine all of them into one file and call all at once?

Comment: Sure, as long as you're not using the "magic DI", you can minify AngularJS files into one file.

Comment: Minification is usually performed during a build process.  Are you using any build processes at the moment?  If not it would be worth investigating some for your platform minfication is common to many build processes.  And yes you could combine them into one file.  With the bootstrap for your app last.

Comment: we're not using build process at the moment.. just want to clarify.. suppose i use one module per page.. is it better to load the scripts when needed (e.g: use ui-router resolve and oclazyload to load the invoice_module for the invoices page). Or simply just combine all of the app files into one and load them all at once

Answer (score 2):

You can merge all your JS modules in a single file, but you need to keep your views in separate files as you are including views by their file names.

You can use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for merging and minifying all your stuff, it will reduce your time.

One caveat is that when you inject a module into another controller or service, use an array instead of using a direct function.

For example:

```js
//This will break your application after minification process.
angular.controller('myController', function($scope) {

})

//Use this schema which will be useful after minification process
angular.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  }
])
```

Comment: no, not mad, just a little surprised. I try to answer to the best of my ability, as I'm sure you do, too. It's rather frustrating when an answer is downvoted not because it's wrong or poorly written, but just to stamp competition.

Comment: I think someone is not happy with mine answer also. But this is not the good thing to downvote only for competition to get more votes

Comment: you are right :) Competition is good only as long as it encourages users to ask better questions, and give better answers, in a positive fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the AngularJS documentation provides a lengthy article on the things to look out for when minifying your AngularJS application:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

The main thing to look out for is that minification can break the "magical dependency injection" if you are using that, but there are ways to manage this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grunt. Grunt have ngmin module which take care of angularjs specific minimization. Below is snippet task which can used for minimization and other optimization. More detail can be found at http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-grunt-angularjs-front

```
 grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'ngconstant:production',
        'compass:server',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concat',
        'ngmin',
        'copy:dist',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [John Papa style guide about minification](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection) for tips on how to do this in build versions of your code

For your dev environment you will not want the minification and manually adding these files get annoying quick. Check out [Hottowel Yeoman generator](https://github.com/johnpapa/generator-hottowel)  (mainly the gulp) for how to set this up for auto injection into the index.html

Here is the snippet from gulp, if you are familiar with the syntax

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
log('Wiring the bower dependencies into the html');

var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var options = config.getWiredepDefaultOptions();

return gulp
    .src(config.index)
    .pipe(wiredep(options))
    .pipe($.inject(gulp.src(config.js)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.client));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a maven build system to do this. This post assumes knowledge of Maven. There are also changes required as mentioned in another answer that must be made to your Angularjs code to allow for minification.

Here is a sample of the POM profile

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>         
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>         
            <version>1.6.2</version>         
            <executions>             
                <execution>
                    <id>default-minify</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase><!-- When omitted defaults to 'process-resources' -->
                    <configuration>
                        <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                        <jsSourceDir>app</jsSourceDir>
                        <jsSourceIncludes>
                            <jsSourceInclude>app.js</jsSourceInclude>
                            <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                        </jsSourceIncludes>
                        <jsTargetDir>min/js</jsTargetDir>
                        <jsFinalFile>app-min-final.js</jsFinalFile>
                        <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

This uses the `minify-maven-plugin`.

Before the maven `package` phase, the `prepare-package` phase below is executed.

You can specify the source dir (jsSourceDir) and the output dir (jsTargetDir).

To package the war you will need to use the `maven-war-plugin` plugin below

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>prepare-war</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exploded</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>default-war</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>war</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    <warSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warSourceExcludes>app/**.js</warSourceExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```